# Requests/aiohttp: closing response objects

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp, python-3.7

I'm a bit confused about the need to `.close()` a response object in both `requests` and `aiohttp`.  (Note that this is a separate instance method than `session.close()`--I'm talking about the response object itself.)

- Does `Response` (`requests`) or `ClientResponse` (`aiohttp`) ever need explicitly call `.close()`?
- If not, what is the purpose of using the response itself as a context manager?  (`async with session.request('GET', 'https://www.pastebin.com'`) below.)  Why define the two dunder methods for this if it gets closed implicitly as shown below?

**Some simple tests (below) seem to imply that responses are closed automatically when they are defined inside of a Session context manager.**  (Which itself calls `self.close()` in `__exit__` or `__aexit__`.  But this is the closing of the Session, not the Response object.)

#### Example - `requests`

```
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> with requests.Session() as s:
...     resp = s.request('GET', 'https://www.pastebin.com')
...     resp.raise_for_status()
...     print(resp.raw.closed)  # `raw` is urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object
...     print(resp.raw._pool)
...     print(resp.raw._connection)
...     c = resp.text
... 
True
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pastebin.com', port=443)
None
>>>
>>> while 1:
...     print(resp.raw.closed)
...     print(resp.raw._pool)
...     print(resp.raw._connection)
...     break
... 
True
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pastebin.com', port=443)
None
```

#### Example - `aiohttp`

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> import aiohttp
>>>
>>> async def get():
...     async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
...         # The response is already closed after this `with` block.
...         # Why would it need to be used as a context manager?
...         resp = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.pastebin.com')
...         print(resp._closed)
...         print(resp._connection)
...         print(resp._released)
...         c = await resp.text()
...     print()
...     print(resp._closed)
...     print(resp._connection)
...     print(resp._released)
...     return c
... 
>>> c = asyncio.run(get())  # Python 3.7 +
False
Connection<ConnectionKey(host='pastebin.com', port=443, is_ssl=True, ssl=None, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None, proxy_headers_hash=None)>
False

True
None
False
```

---

Here's the source for `requests.models.Response`.  What does "Should not normally need to be called explicitly" mean?  What are the exceptions?

```
def close(self):
    """Releases the connection back to the pool. Once this method has been
    called the underlying ``raw`` object must not be accessed again.
    *Note: Should not normally need to be called explicitly.*
    """
    if not self._content_consumed:
        self.raw.close()

    release_conn = getattr(self.raw, 'release_conn', None)
    if release_conn is not None:
        release_conn()
```

Comment: My understanding is They will automatically close when script done

Comment: It seems to be so.  But through what means?  @kcorlidy  I want to know how the `Response` itself is closed when the Session calls `__exit__` or `__aexit__`

Comment: In aiohttp , The context manager will trigger `__aexit__` when you quit `with..as`. `__aexit__` contain self.close() which can close `TCPConnector`. You can watch `aiohttp/client.py` line 864 803 150 132.

Comment: `requests` is more complex , i found it is using `PoolManager`. And open url with code such as `manager.connection_from_host('xx.com').urlopen(url="http://xx.com/",method="get")`. But i still do not know why the connection will shutdown after finished. btw When exit `with...as` the `close()` will iterate each connection and close it (view session.py 733)

Comment: It will be closed after `urlopen` finished. just try my code on comment and `print(x.closed)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Requests`: You need not explicitly call `close()`. request will automatically close after finished because it bases on urlopen (this is why `resp.raw.closed` is True), This is the simplified code after i watched `session.py` and `adapters.py`:

```
from urllib3 import PoolManager
import time
manager = PoolManager(10)
conn = manager.connection_from_host('host1.example.com')
conn2 = manager.connection_from_host('host2.example.com')
res = conn.urlopen(url="http://host1.example.com/",method="get")
print(len(manager.pools))
manager.clear()
print(len(manager.pools))
print(res.closed)

#2
#0
#True
```

Then what did the `__exit__` do? It uses to clear `PoolManager(self.poolmanager=PoolManager(...))` and `proxy`.

```
# session.py
def __exit__(self, *args): #line 423
    self.close()
def close(self): #line 733
    for v in self.adapters.values():
        v.close()

# adapters.py
# v.close()
def close(self): #line 307
        self.poolmanager.clear()
        for proxy in self.proxy_manager.values():
            proxy.clear()
```

So when should you need to use `close()` , as the note said ***Releases the connection back to the pool***, because `DEFAULT_POOLSIZE = 10`(http/https are independent). That means if you want to access more than 10 website with one session , you can chose to close some you do not need otherwise manager will close connection from the first to the newest when you have one more. But actually you need not to care about this , you can specify pool size and it would not waste much time to rebuild connection

`aiohttp` aiohttp.ClientSession()  is using one TCPConnector for all requests. When it triggered `__aexit__` ,  `self._connector` will be closed.

Edit: `s.request()` is set up a connection from host but it did not get response. `await resp.text()` can only be done after got response, if you did not do such step(wait for response), you will exit without having response.

```
if connector is None: #line 132
    connector = TCPConnector(loop=loop)
...
self._connector = connector #line 151
# connection timeout
try:
    with CeilTimeout(real_timeout.connect,loop=self._loop):
    assert self._connector is not None
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
        req,
        traces=traces,
        timeout=real_timeout
        )
...
async def close(self) -> None:
        if not self.closed:
            if self._connector is not None and self._connector_owner:
                self._connector.close()
            self._connector = None
...
async def __aexit__(self,
                       ...) -> None:
        await self.close()
```

This is code to show what i said

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time

async def get():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
        # The response is already closed after this `with` block.
        # Why would it need to be used as a context manager?
        resp = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.stackoverflow.com')
        resp2 = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.github.com')
        print("resp:",resp._closed)
        print("resp:",resp._connection)
        print("resp2:",resp2._closed)
        print("resp2:",resp2._connection)
        s.close()
        print(s.closed)
        c = await resp.text()
        d = await resp2.text()

    print()
    print(s._connector)
    print("resp:",resp._closed)
    print("resp:",resp._connection)
    print("resp2:",resp2._closed)
    print("resp2:",resp2._connection)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(get())  # Python 3.5 +

#dead loop
```

Comment: Interesting, first example with pool manager is especially helpful.  At this point I'm wondering two things:

Comment: You mention, "The response is already closed after this `with` block.  Why would it need to be used as a context manager?".  But see such an example straight from the aiohttp Client docs: https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_advanced.html

Comment: Secondly, it doesn't make a ton of sense that `resp` is closed before you even call its `.text()` method (and still within the `with` block before `__aexit__` has been called for the session).  Why would `resp` be closed while `resp2` shows `False`?

Comment: `Why would it need to be used as a context manager?` In `requests` , context manager will close session , actually it cleared poolmanager (my second part code display). In `aiohttp`, context manager is use to close TCPConnector, but `s.request` just build up connection from host , request is still running. `await x.text()` only can be done after response got. That is why if you remove `await x.text()` that you will get `x._connection -> Connection<ConnectionKey...`. extra: if you close `ClientSession` before `await x.text()` it will get into dead loop

Comment: `resp._connection or resp2._connection` will remain if exit before got response. But actually connection was closed. @BradSolomon