# Seeking explanation of aiohttp response/connection closing behavior

Tags: python, python-requests, connection, aiohttp, python-asyncio

In my attempts to build a proxychecker as a sort of crash course in NetworkIO and asyncio/aiohttp, I've encountered some problems involving unclosed connections which took me over to StackOverflow and this gem of a post ([Requests/aiohttp: closing response objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103482/requests-aiohttp-closing-response-objects)) that will serve as the basis of my questions. I believe that this post will be most helpful to anyone who wishes to answer if I give the complete run down of things my end so, here we go:

In the included above StackOverflow post can be found a portion of code (which I will refer to on out as the 'base code') in the top answer like so:

```
async def get():
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
    # The response is already closed after this `with` block.
    # Why would it need to be used as a context manager?
    resp = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.stackoverflow.com')
    resp2 = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.github.com')
    print("resp:",resp._closed)
    print("resp:",resp._connection)
    print("resp2:",resp2._closed)
    print("resp2:",resp2._connection)
    s.close()
    print(s.closed)
    c = await resp.text()
    d = await resp2.text()

print()
print(s._connector)
print("resp:",resp._closed)
print("resp:",resp._connection)
print("resp2:",resp2._closed)
print("resp2:",resp2._connection)
```

**[1]**
Upon running this base code without making edits (besides adding some code at the end to actually run it), I noticed a peculiarity. **resp will close 'organically' while resp2 will not, meaning resp2 and its connection remain unclosed**.

Curious now, I added a third statement:

```
resp = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.stackoverflow.com')
resp2 = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.github.com')
resp3 = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.google.com')
```

as well as further code written in a similar style to the base code in order to show terminal output checking whether resp3 and its connection closes organically.
**[2] Upon running such modified base code, I found then that now resp and resp2 close organically, but resp3 does not - response and connection stay unclosed**

Curious to see if there was an easy fix to this, I tried added an asyncio sleep statement to see if that would make a difference.

```
resp = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.stackoverflow.com')
resp2 = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.github.com')
resp3 = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.google.com')
await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
```

**[3]**
And to my surprise I found that **sleeping for as little as 0.1, allowed all three response/connections to terminate organically.**

At this point, I decided to test another URL for resp3 and see if I encountered the same behavior.

```
resp = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.stackoverflow.com')
resp2 = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.github.com')
resp3 = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.deviantart.com')
await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
```

**[4]**
It was on the run of this code that I found something that truly reared my curiosity, ultimately leading to this post. **resp1 and resp2 will close organically but resp3 does not despite having the "await asyncio.sleep(0.1)" statement that allowed resp3 to close as desired when resp3 pointed at Google's domain.** To further investigate, I cranked up the sleep to:

```
await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

But to no avail. It seems plausible to assume that the response/connection to DeviantArt will not terminate no matter how long of an interval I specify to asyncio.sleep().

**[5]**
Finally, I decided that maybe the problem had to do specifically with DeviantArt as a site so I rewrote the trial code like so:

```
resp = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.deviantart.com')
resp2 = await s.request('GET', 'https://www.deviantart.com/daily-deviations')
await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
```

But to no avail: **neither resp nor resp2 close at all.**

Which brings me to the series of questions I have that I would truly appreciate answers to / explanations of: *Note that each question number corresponds to a each bracketed number observation*

1. Why does resp2 not close by itself when resp1 does?
2. Why does resp2 close by itself in addition to resp1 while resp3 (from Google) does not?
3. Why does using 'await asyncio.sleep(0.1)' make such a difference as to close a response (in this case resp3 from Google) which normally does not close by itself?
4. Why does the resp3 from DeviantArt not close by itself despite having the same 'await asyncio.sleep(0.1)' statement that helped close the resp3 from Google in the previous trial as well as another attempt of doing 'await asyncio.sleep(10)?'
5. Why does neither resp1 nor resp2 from DeviantArt close by itself?

This last question is more based on the SO post that I've linked at the start of this post but:

- I understand from the StackOverflow post I've linked above that 'await response.text()' will help close the responses by waiting for them but what I do not understand is why this is even necessary; it seems to me like that should be handled by the 'response = await request' - keyword being **await** which one would think means that the such a statement would not finish executing without waiting for the response to 'arrive' fully.

On a final note: I'd like to point out that I have learned how to solve unclosed response / connection problems. In case anyone starting off with aiohttp makes it here and doesn't know how, it can be done via awaiting text(), using response context managers, or even just using well placed response.close() calls. But as the title suggests, I am quite interested in hearing what's going on under the hood.

I appreciate any and all help; any recommended resources for aiohttp are welcome  as well.
Thanks in advance!

Bumps: 10